# Why does Module#define_method ignore method naming "rules"

Tags: ruby, syntax

The following won't work as a method definition (unless we're defining a singleton method for `the`):

```
def the.dot
  :dot
end
```

But, with [Module#`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-define_method) it works fine:

```
define_method('the.dot') { :dot }
#=> :"the.dot"
method('the.dot')
#=> #<Method: main.the.dot>
```

Calling it the usual way will throw an exception:

```
the.dot
#=> NameError: undefined local variable or method `the' for main:Object
```

But there are ways to call this method:

```
method('the.dot').call
#=> :dot
public_send('the.dot')
#=> :dot
```

Why does `define_method` ignore method naming rules by allowing almost anything to be a method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`define_method` does not ignore the naming rules. Those allowed by `define_method` are allow by Ruby in the first place. It is simply the case that, with `def` keyword, you can only define a restricted groupes of names.

Answer (score 1):

`define_method` takes a *symbol* as it's first argument. If you pass it a string it will convert that string into a symbol, which in this case looks really weird as `:"the.dot"` but that is a symbol just like `:thedot`, but Ruby quotes it because otherwise it would break ruby syntax.

```
> "the.dot".to_sym
=> :"the.dot"
> "thedot".to_sym
=> :thedot
> "the dot".to_sym
=> :"the dot"
> define_method("the dot") { "yep, this works" }
=> :"the dot"
> method("the dot").call
=> "yep, this works"
```